# Capture multiple substrings in one group

Tags: python, regex

Now, I have a folder path will contain a database table name and a ID, looks like:

```
path = '/something/else/TableName/000/123/456/789'
```

Of course I can match `TableName/000/123/456/789` then split them by python script.

```
import re
matched = re.findall(r'.*?/(\w+(?:/\d+){4})', path)[0]  # TableName/000/123/456/789
split_text = matched.split('/')  # ['TableName', '000', '123', '456', '789']
table_name = split_text[0]  # 'TableName'
id = int(''.join(split_text[1:]))  # 123456789
```

[.*?/(\w+(?:/\d+){4})](https://regex101.com/r/Fy7N15/1)

But I want to know, if there any function provided by regex can finish it in one step? I've tried these ways:

```
re.match(r'.*?/(?P<table_name>\w+)(?:/(?P<id>\d+)){4}', path).groupdict()  # {'table_name': 'TableName', 'id': '789'}
re.split(r'.*?/(\w+)(?:/(\d+)){4}', path)  # ['', 'TableName', '789', '']
re.sub(r'(.*?/)\w+(?:(/)\d+){4}', '', path)  # '', full string has been replaced
```

[.*?/(?P\w+)(?:/(?P\d+)){4}](https://regex101.com/r/Fy7N15/2)

[.*?/(\w+)(?:/(\d+)){4}](https://regex101.com/r/Fy7N15/3)

Is there anyway else? Or I must use the python script above? I hope the result is `{'table_name': 'TableName', 'id': '000123456789'}` or `('TableName', '000123456789')`, at least `('TableName', '000', '123', '456', '789')`.

Comment: I think you should go with pythonic way instead of doing regex works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to avoid using quantifier:

```
re.findall('(\w+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)', path)

[('TableName', '000', '123', '456', '789')]
```

Comment: This will 100% work if the ordering in the path is fixed

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand me. I hope the result is `('TableName', '000123456789')`, at least `('TableName', '000', '123', '456', '789')`

Comment: Simplest way is to avoid using quantifiers:

re.findall('(\w+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)', path)

[('TableName', '000', '123', '456', '789')]

Comment: OK, maybe you are right. I'm only afraid that later there will be more id levels. If no other choice, I think I will choose between your answer and the pythonic way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to expand the grouping.

```
>>> match=re.search(r'.*?/(\w+)(?:/(\d+))(?:/(\d+))(?:/(\d+))(?:/(\d+))',a)
>>> match.groups()
('TableName', '000', '123', '456', '789')
```